# Skrollr - Middle Section to stop and rotate elements

Tags: css, parallax, skrollr

This is my requirement (Also see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZUWu.jpg for visual):

1) Say 4 sections:

div 01
div 02
div 03
div 04

2) My second div02 has an element which needs to translate, post the div02 reaches center of page. Scrolling stopped, just animation happening as user is scrolling. (position fixed i assume)

3) After translation is complete, the scrolling needs to continue, as usual, and all div's move up.

Any help, on how to get this done? I have been trying to shuttle between position relative to fixed at data-center, but not getting the feel.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see what you have already tried?

Comment: This is what I set up: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNGaYr?editors=110
Just not working - messed up! Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: After some research and good trial - I think I pretty much got what I needed. So that it helps someone, I am putting the edited code here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNGaYr?editors=110

This doc reference/example, helped a lot: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/examples/pausing.html